# Doubt regarding cyclic group of prime power order

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

Let $G=\langle x,y\rangle$ be a cyclic group of prime power order. Then is it true that $G$ is generated by either $x$ or $y$?

What we tried:

Let $G=\langle z\rangle.$ Then $x=z^m, y=z^n$ for some integer $m,n.$ So $G=\langle x,y\rangle=\langle z^{gcd(m,n)}\rangle=\langle z\rangle.$ This gives $gcd(m,n)=1.$  By given condition, the order of $z$ is $p^r,$ for some prime $p$ and integer $r.$ Need to show either $m$ or $n$ is 1.

Comment: The subgroups of a cyclic group of prime power order form a chain, so yes. Show that if A and B are two subgroups, one in of the two contains the other; then using that notice that if (x) and (y) are proper subgroups then so is (x,y).

Comment: With regard to your proof attempt - there are many possible choices of generator $z$ in general. You may well have picked one that is not equal to $x$ or $y$, so with $m,n$ not equal to $1$, and yet still have $x,y,z$ all being generators of the group. Furthermore, just because $z^g$ is a generator, it does not mean that $g=1$. Instead, what you have to somehow prove is that $x$ and/or $y$ is a generator, i.e. that its order is the prime power order of the group.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: It is not true, consider e.g. $G=C_6, x=z^2, y=z^3$.

EDIT: Oops, $G$ is of prime power order. It may help to write $m=kp^i$ and $n=lp^j$ with $k,l\nmid p$. What can you say about $i,j$?

Comment: 6 is not a power of a prime, though.

Answer (score 1):

You might write $G=\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$, $(x)=p^k \mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$, $(y)=p^m\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$. Then, assume without loss of generality that $k \geq m$ (otherwise, interchange the roles of $x$ and $y$). It follows that $(x) \subset (y)$, so $(x,y)=(y)$. The result follows from setting $G=(x,y)$.